# How I can use Gson in Retrofit library?

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I used Retrofit for send request and receive the response in android but have problem when I want convert response which come from the sever it is always give me `Exception`:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
```

When response from server should give me list from movies so I need put all this movies in list.

`Movie` (Model Class):

```
public class Movie {
    public Movie() {}
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    private String movieTitle;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    private String movieVoteAverage;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String movieOverview;
    ............  
}
```

`GitMovieApi` Class:

```
public interface GitMovieApi {
    @GET("/3/movie/{movie}")  
    public void getMovie(@Path("movie") String typeMovie,@Query("api_key") String  keyApi, Callback<Movie> response);    
}
```

`RestAdapter` configuration:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Movie.class, new UserDeserializer()).create()))
                    .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org")
                    .build(); 
                     GitMovieApi git = restAdapter.create(GitMovieApi.class);  
                git.getMovie("popular", "Keyapi", new Callback<Movie>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Movie movie, Response response) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "s", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

**UserDeserializer:**

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Movie> {
        @Override
        public Movie deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOF,
                                 JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {
            JsonElement userJson = new JsonParser().parse("results");
            return new Gson().fromJson(userJson, Movie.class);
        }
    }
```

**Json(Response):**

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/tbhdm8UJAb4ViCTsulYFL3lxMCd.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        53,
        28,
        12
      ],
      "id": 76341,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Mad Max: Fury Road",
      "overview": "An apocalyptic story set in the furthest.",
      "release_date": "2015-05-15",
      "poster_path": "/kqjL17yufvn9OVLyXYpvtyrFfak.jpg",
      "popularity": 48.399601,
      "title": "Mad Max: Fury Road",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.6,
      "vote_count": 2114
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/sLbXneTErDvS3HIjqRWQJPiZ4Ci.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        10751,
        16,
        12,
        35
      ],
      "id": 211672,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Minions",
      "overview": "Minions Stuart.",
      "release_date": "2015-06-25",
      "poster_path": "/s5uMY8ooGRZOL0oe4sIvnlTsYQO.jpg",
      "popularity": 31.272707,
      "title": "Minions",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.8,
      "vote_count": 1206
    },     
],
  "total_pages": 11871,
  "total_results": 237415
}
```

Comment: the content of `results` is not a Movie. It is a list of movies

Comment: `new JsonParser().parse("results")` that's not how it works. this is trying to parse `"results"` which is a String. You want to use the JsonElement that is given to you.

Comment: I know the results is list from movie  but when you see Gson you can see it was one object and I try to get that object {...} then access to list movie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You don't even need to make a custom deserializer here.

Get rid of `UserDeserializer` entirely, it's not needed. Your query is returning a list of movies, so make your callback to an object that actually reads the list of movies:

```
public class MovieList {
    @SerializedName("results")
    List<Movie> movieList;
    // you can also add page, total_pages, and total_results here if you want
}
```

Then your `GitMovieApi` class would be:

```
public interface GitMovieApi {
    @GET("/3/movie/{movie}")  
    public void getMovie(@Path("movie") String typeMovie,
                @Query("api_key") String keyApi,
                Callback<MovieList> response);    
}
```

Your `RestAdapter`:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder()).create()))
                .setEndpoint("http://api.themoviedb.org")
                .build(); 
                 GitMovieApi git = restAdapter.create(GitMovieApi.class);
```

The problem is *not* that you have written the `Deserializer` incorrectly (although, you have, but it's okay because you don't need it, `JsonParser` is **not** how you do it), but the default deserialization behavior should work just fine for you. Use the above code and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

In Retrofit 2 it is even simpler. Your `GitMovieApi` class:

```
interface MoviesApi {
    @GET("/3/movie/{movie}")
    Call<MovieList> getMovies(@Path("movie") String typeMovie,
                              @Query("api_key") String keyApi);
}
```

And than you just need to create a Retrofit object, and make a callback:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MOVIES_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
service = retrofit.create(MoviesApi.class);

Call<MovieList> mlc = service.getMovies(getArguments().getString(ARG_MOVIE_TYPE), getString(R.string.THE_MOVIE_DB_API_TOKEN));
mlc.enqueue(new Callback<MovieList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieList> call, Response<MovieList> response) {
            movies = response.body().movieList;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieList> call, Throwable t) {}
});
```