# Parse RequestBody as a request paramter in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have to parse the following web service:

**http://api.mytracemobile.com/mobile.svc/getHotelApp?data={"AvailabilitySearch": 
{"Authority": { "Currency": "USD" },"Cityname": "Jaipur, India", "CheckInDate": "2017-11-18","CheckOutDate": "2017-11-19", "Searchid": "111111",  "Room": [{"Guests": {"Adult": [{ "Title": "Mr" },{ "Title": "Mr" }]}},{"Guests": {"Adult": { "Title": "Mr" }}}],"Nationality": "IN"}}**

How can I create a RequestBody for it so **?data=** also includes in that request body.
Please let me know how this will be implemented 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Read about [GSON and Retrofit](https://onelonecoder.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/andorid-restful-client-using-retrofit-gson/), there are sufficient articles on both.**

Instead of above data sample, Check the dummy sample and Model class to understand the process

```
 Sample: A:{B:"",C:"",D:[{D1:""},{D1:""}]} 

 Models: 
   Class1 {@SerializedName("A") private Class2 a; }

   Class2 { @SerializedName("B") private String b;
             @SerializedName("C") private String c;
             @SerializedName("D") private Arraylist<Class3> d; } 
   Class3 {   @SerializedName("D1") private String D1; }
```

Note: Add Getter setter or constructor in Models to access the values.

After this, You can decrypt the JSON response just by passing reference of Class1.

Read about GSON(for @SerializedName) and then about Retrofit to fetch JSON Response also check this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490011/how-i-can-use-gson-in-retrofit-library) post.

Comment: Ankur I created my JSON but stuck in creation Request body

Comment: Can u  add snippet of the code so that we can solve it.